# Spring data rest nulls out field in HandleBeforeSave

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm facing a scenario with one entity *User* which has a field *password* (among others, but those are not important). I want to handle 2 scenarios:

1. PUT with *password* field should actually update the password which the one provided
2. PUT without *password* field should leave the password intact.

While the first scenario works fine, I can't find solution for the other. I tried with Event handlers like this

```
    @HandleBeforeSave
    fun handleUserUpdate(user: User) {
        if (user.password == null || user.password == "") {
            val storedUser = systemRunner.runInSystemContext { userRepository.findOne(user.id!!) }
            user.password = storedUser.password
        } else {
            user.password = passwordEncoder.encode(user.password)
        }
    }
```

But this won't work. Spring DATA REST already nulls out the field in the paramter provided (and it is in the same JPA session so obviously I get the same result from the DB). I probably could request to refresh the entity but then I would loose other changes? How to do this?

Comment: For a partial update use PATCH https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_patch and not PUT. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_put

Answer (score 0):

That's strange... In my java project all works as expected, both for PUT and PATCH requests:

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(User.class)
public class UserEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void handleBeforeSave(User user) { // user: "User[id:1]"
        //...
    }
}
```

But what about encoding the password right in the User class? For example:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    public static final PasswordEncoder ENCODER = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    //...

    @PreUpdate
    @PrePersist
    private void encodePassword() {
        password = !StringUtils.isEmpty(password) ? ENCODER.encode(password) : null;
    } 
}
```

In my opinion this solution is better cause it does't depend on the REST layer...

Comment: But my question was how to make spring not null out field which are not present but leave them intact?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the anwser. Please use either patch with standard content type json or with "application/merge-patch+json". Please follow [RFC specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386) which states that to null out f field and update a field to value "z" in

```
 {
       "a": "b",
       "c": {
           "d": "e",
           "f": "g"
       }
 }
```

You need to patch "application/merge-patch+json"

```
       {
         "a":"z",
         "c": {
            "f": null
         }
       }
```

Or you can do something like this

```
    @Transient
    var oldPassword: String? = null

    @PostLoad
    fun rememberOldUser() {
        this.oldPassword = this.password;
    }
```